# Css scroll-snap not working properly on every device/browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, scroll-snap

I am building a website with a scroll-snap feature : [sharpchicken.com](http://sharpchicken.com/version%20finale.html). It worked well on MacBook/safari. With chrome the speed of scroll between snap is extremely slow. On iOS/safari it scroll a bit too fast (not sure). On some other combo like android/samsung browser it completely glitch. Do you know what I can do it work more like the website [Tesla.com](https://www.tesla.com) Thanks for your time and help.

I have tried :  scroll-behavior: smooth with no results

Comment: You are going to have to share some code in your question if you want help with that code.  Please make it easy for people to answer your question and help you.

Comment: I linked the website. I am not sure what code should I share?

Comment: If you aren't sure what code to share, then it's really hard for anyone else to take a guess.     Please read over this StackOverflow article about how and why you need to create [A Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when asking a question

Comment: What I mean is since I don't what to modify/add it's irrelevant to share specific code since you can see it all on the website.

Comment: Isn't your question about this scoll-snap feature? I would imagine the code that does this is probably relevant to include in your question. I don't want to go digging through your source code to find this since you know where this code is.  If you can make a minimal reproducible example using your code that makes it much easier to debug without all kinds of unrelated website stuff getting in the way.